# How to make zoom to selected feature permanent in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I was wondering if there is an option in QGIS so that I don't need to click on a feature in the attribute table and afterwards click on zoom to selected feature.

I am hoping to navigate through the table and the map to follow the rows that I am selecting/editing in the attribute table.

What would be the best approach to achieve this result?

Edit: For those interested in alternative solutions, AutoCAD Map has this option. They call it auto-scroll & auto-zoom. It's exactly what I wished for, but at a very different price point than QGIS.

Comment: See if the ZoomView plugin does what you want. The description is a bit ambiguous. It adds a dock panel "showing a magnification of the map canvas around a selected point."

Comment: @csk thanks for trying, but no, it does not do what I want. This plugin zooms in wherever you click, but what I want is automatic "zoom to extents" while I navigate through features in the attribute table.